# Ошибка открытия файла MS Access после сжатия

Tags: access, windows-7, ms-access

У меня возникла следующая проблема. Есть база данных MS Access, разделённая на два файла: в одном хранятся сами данные (только таблицы), в другом — формы вместе с отчётами и прочим, причём у обоих в параметрах стоит флажок "Сжимать при закрытии". Мне понадобилось внести изменения в структуру одной из таблиц, но сделать этого мне не удалось: сначала выскочило окно с предупреждением о том, что после сжатия исходный файл удалить не получилось, а потом появилось ещё одно сообщение, что файл, который я собиралась править, не найден. И действительно, он исчез. Хорошо ещё, что резервные копии были на месте...

У меня самой данная проблема воспроизводится, если нет прав доступа на изменение содержания каталога, где сидит файл Access, но при этом исходный файл не исчезает и добавляется ещё один, блокировочный. А там, где мне нужно внести правки, права у пользователя на изменение есть и он вообще работает в БД один.

Вопрос у меня в связи со всем этим такой: что я не так делаю? Дополнительная информация: ОС Windows 7, MS Access версии 2013, а сами файлы версии 2002 или 2003.

Comment: Малопонятно... В какой из БД вносились изменения в структуру? Была ли при этом открыта в среде вторая БД? *сначала выскочило окно с предупреждением о том, что после сжатия исходный файл удалить не получилось, а потом появилось ещё одно сообщение, что файл, который я собиралась править, не найден. И действительно, он исчез.* Угу, и где-то осталась валяться непереименованная БД во временном файле со странным именем... поищи, что ли... PS. И нафига "Сжимать при закрытии" на базе с данными - она никогда не открывается интерфейсом?

Comment: Изменения вносились в тот файл БД, где только таблицы. Никакой другой БД в открытом состоянии не было. По поводу флажка: его ставила не я, база тоже не моя. По поводу интерфейса: в нём есть связанные таблицы, которые ссылаются на те, что в отдельном mdb-файле (который я и пыталась править).

Comment: *Изменения вносились в тот файл БД, где только таблицы. Никакой другой БД в открытом состоянии не было.* БД лежала на сетевом ресурсе? БД не была открыта монопольно? *выскочило окно с предупреждением о том, что после сжатия исходный файл удалить не получилось* Код ошибки не помните? 2? 5? другой?

Comment: @Akina, БД **не** на сетевом ресурсе и ею пользуется только один человек. Что касается _предупреждения_, то код сейчас не вспомню (потом ещё раз воспроизведу ситуацию у себя). Его текст начинался так: "_Приложению MS Access не удаётся удалить {название файла с таблицами} после сжатия. Сжатой БД присвоено имя {новый файл}..._", а потом шло объяснение, как работает сжатие файлов, и рекомендовалось проверить права доступа к файлам. Инфу по самому предупреждению мне пробить не удалось.

Comment: @Akina, код ошибки, где говорилось, что файл не найден, 3024.